# Creating WishList/ShopingCart for ASP.net mvc problems with foreign keys

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, t-sql

Creating shop application and having two main tables `Product` and `Customer`. The aim is to create an `Order` table where customer can choose from the productgetall list and add it to Order table.

Customer Table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customer] 
(
    [CustomerId] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName]  NVARCHAR(40)   NOT NULL,
    [LastName]   NVARCHAR(20)   NOT NULL,
    [Email]      NVARCHAR(60)   NOT NULL,
    [Photo]      VARBINARY(MAX) NULL,
    [password]   VARCHAR(300)   NULL,
    [Country]    VARCHAR(50)    NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Customer] 
         PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([CustomerId] ASC)
);
```

Product table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Product] 
(
    [ProductId]       INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [ProductName]     NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [ProductDetails]  TEXT         NULL,
    [ProductPrice]    INT          NOT NULL,
    [ProductCategory] NVARCHAR(50) NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ProductId] ASC)
);
```

Order table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Order] 
(
    [OrderId]    INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [CustomerId] INT     NOT NULL,
    [ProductId]  INT     NOT NULL,
    [Date]       DATE    NULL,
    [Time]       TIME(7) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [ORDER_PK] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([OrderId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [CUSTOMER_FK] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([CustomerId]) 
            REFERENCES [dbo].[Customer] ([CustomerId]) 
                ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [PRODUCT_FK] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([ProductId]) 
            REFERENCES [dbo].[Product] ([ProductId]) 
                ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

C# code to add order

```
public void AddOrder(Order a)
{
    using (DbConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnStr))
    {
        using (DbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 120;
            cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO [dbo].[Order] (CustomerId, ProductId, Date, Time)
                                VALUES (@CustomerId, @ProductId, @Date, @Time)";

            cmd.AddParameter("@CustomerId", a.CustomerId, DbType.Int32);
            cmd.AddParameter("@ProductId", a.ProductId, DbType.Int32);
            cmd.AddParameter("@Date", a.Date, DbType.Date);
            cmd.AddParameter("@Time", a.Time.ToString(), DbType.String);

            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
    }
}
```

While creating through web forms it showing error on `ExecuteScalar`:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "CUSTOMER_FK". The conflict occurred in database "C:\USERS\USER\DESKTOP\2019 5LVL\DBSD\TRYWISHLIST\3\00005466\00005466\APP_DATA\KFCDB.MDF", table "dbo.Customer", column 'CustomerId'. The statement has been terminated

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The `CustomerId` you're sending does not exist in `dbo.Customer`, insert it.